# Running IdentityV4 in Docker ECS Fargate IDX20108The address 'System.String' is not valid as per HTTPS scheme

Tags: docker, https, asp.net-identity, aws-fargate

I have a problem with Authotity adress when it come from an AWS load balancer HTTPS/SSL.
I'm running IdentityServer4 in a ECS Fargate Docker, and this service was configured to use Elastic Load Balancing to distribute traffic. A new listener was created to foward the 443 port with a correct certificate. I cant configure this https as Authority server.

Client:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(setup => setup.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {  
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = "https://account-test.mydomain";
        options.ClientId = "WebMVC";
        options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);
        options.Scope.Add("custom.profile");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });
```

Error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: IDX20108: The address specified 'System.String' is not valid as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps property on IDocumentRetriever to false.
Parameter name: address
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)

Stack Query Cookies Headers
ArgumentException: IDX20108: The address specified 'System.String' is not valid as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps property on IDocumentRetriever to false. Parameter name: address
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(string address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

When i try to use HTTP for Authority : "http://account-test.mydomain" its works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue help me to fix : https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/929

Solution:

Include Use at he IdentityServer and Client:

```
app.Use((context, next) => { 
context.Request.Scheme = "https"; return next(); });
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered similar issue when I host IdentityServer inside a docker behind NGINX. My solution was to configure the forwarded header middleware at Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
  options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
  options.ForwardLimit = 2;
  options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
  options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

and add this before other middleware at Startup.cs Configure method:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

this ensures headers are forwarded when docker is used.